# Syntax error when running my classes on terminal

Tags: python, pandas, luigi

I am trying to create a file using luigi that will take a csv and create output the splits the data up into different dataframes based on whether or not a particular column in the csv contains a particular string

This is the file I created:

```
import luigi
import pandas as pd
import os
class read_file(luigi.Task):
    fileName = luigi.Parameter()
    def run(self):
        full_file = pd.read_csv(self.fileName)
        return full_file[['anonymous_id','channel','context_campaign_content',
                'context_campaign_medium','context_campaign_name',
                'context_campaign_source','context_campaign_term',
                'timestamp','user_id','context_page_url',
                'properties_url','properties_search','context_page_title',
                'properties_path','context_user_agent','properties_referrer','rank']]
    def output(self):
        return full_file
class blog_readers(luigi.Task):
    def run(self):
        read_blog = read_file.full_file[read_file.full_file['properties_url'].str.contains('blog',regex=False)]
        return read_blog
    def requires(self):
        return read_file
    def output(self):
        return read_blog
class logged_in(luigi.Task):
    def run(self):
        logged_in = read_file.full_file[read_file.full_file['properties_url'].str.contains('login',regex=False]
        return logged_in
    def requires(self):
        return read_file
    def output(self):
        return logged_in
if __name__ == '__main__':
    luigi.run()
```

However when I run this file on terminal-

```
python cleanup.py --local-scheduler read_blog --fileName '/Users/**/Desktop/file.csv'
```

I encounter this error message

```
  File "cleancopy.py", line 64
    logged_in = read_file.full_file[read_file.full_file['properties_url'].str.contains('login',regex=False]
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I am not sure what the syntax error is being caused by

Comment: Try creating object something like: `rf = read_file()`. Also, full_file variable is local to your methods. It cannot be accessed from outside class. Hence, just like filename, you need to initiate `full_file` variable

Comment: `logged_in = read_file.full_file[read_file.full_file['properties_url'].str.contains('login',regex=False]` You're missing the closing parentheses on `contains()`.

Comment: That isn't the file you created, because it doesn't even *have* 64 lines, let alone having the line in the error message on line 64.

Comment: @chepner its the file, it doesn't have 64 lines because a lot of lines are lines naming the columns in the csv...which i don't think are relevant to the question..the line logged_in = read_file is in the code I posted

Comment: Then post an error message involving the simplified file shown, so that we have more confidence that you aren't losing the source of the problem in your simplification.